# Regex to replace pipe delimited array to html

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Am trying to use regex to manipulate the following string

```
hello.jpg|world.jpg
```

to

```
<li>http://example.com/hello.jpg</li>
<li>http://example.com/world.jpg</li>
```

Any pointers?

Comment: regex in what language? Javascript?

Comment: I added the the javascript tag, please approve the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the output to be a string of HTML rather than actual DOM nodes you've got a choice between a RegExp or using `split`:

```js
var str = 'hello.jpg|world.jpg|globe.jpg';

// Using RegExp
var str1 = str.replace(/([^|]+)\|?/g, '<li>http://example.com/$1</li>');

// Using split/map/join with ES6
var str2 = str.split('|').map(img => `<li>http://example.com/${img}</li>`).join('');

// Using split/map/join old school
var str3 = str.split('|').map(function(img) {
    return '<li>http://example.com/' + img + '</li>';
}).join('');

console.log(str1);
console.log(str2);
console.log(str3);
```

Note that none of these examples HTML encodes the image name. If that's a concern you couldn't use the RegExp approach but the other two could easily be adapted.

If you wanted to create the actual DOM nodes then it might be easiest to use one of the approaches above to generate a string and then just set the `innerHTML` of your `<ul>`. If you wanted to cut out the middleman and go straight to the DOM you could try something like this:

```js
var ul = document.getElementById('list');

var str = 'hello.jpg|world.jpg|globe.jpg';

str.split('|').forEach(function(img) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    
    li.innerText = 'http://example.com/' + img;
    
    ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

By using `innerText` the HTML encoding has been accounted for.

Answer (score 2):

[split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) your input and add it to your html DOM

```html
<ul id="list">

</ul>

<script>
  var html = "hello.jpg|world.jpg".split("|");
  for (var vl in html) {
  
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    
    li.innerHTML = "http://example.com/" + html[vl];
    
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
    
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Even though it uses split rather than regex that was asked for, this is the best solution posted so far

Comment: Thanks @DarrenH, feel free to add if you want to.

Comment: I actually feel split is a better choice than regex for this particular case, regex just complicates it needlessly. Keep it simple where you can!

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you wanted to use regex, you can also use `split()`

The `split()` function takes in a particular character you want to split a string by and stores it as an array. You can then use each item in that array to do what ever with... In this instance, I appended each one into a new variable it and inserted it into a `div`.

```js
    var str = "hello.jpg|world.jpg";
    var res = str.split("|");
    var html = "<li>http://example.com/"+res[0]+"</li><li>http://example.com/"+res[1]+"</li>";
    
  document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: This works when you have two elements, but they can be more than that. keep it dynamic.

Comment: Yes, OP only gave two elements and specified the given string. You can just wrap this in a simple loop to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simply match the everything but the pipe (`|`)

```
var myString = 'hello.jpg|world.jpg';
var matches = myString.match(/[^|]{1,}/g);
```

Then do whatever you want with the matched items, like add them to the DOM.

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = matches[i];
    container.appendChild(li);
}
```